# accessing a website database by adding an edit text value to the url

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am looking to access my website database and add a user to it through an edit text and onClick. i have most of the app finished. to do this from the pc is very easy as i just add the user number in the appropriate place in the URL and they are added to the database.

this is the URl with a user added

http://something.com/user/426561?token=dYG8hW5TY4LBU8jfPb10D3IcsSx8RTo6

I want to insert a number value where the 426561 is by using edit text. this is what i have so far and my websitethrows an invalid user number error which it is supposed to do.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    edttext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    Button tutorial2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      tutorial2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra("edttext", edttext.getText().toString());
               intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://something.com/user/= edttext?token=dYG8hW5TY4LBU8jfPb10D3IcsSx8RTo6"));
              startActivity(intent);    

        }

      });
```

I have  added to the URL but obviously I am not doing it correctly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this. Putting extras does not replace data in intent

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://example.com/user/"+edttext.getText() +"?token=dYG8hW5TY4LBU8jfPb10D3IcsSx8RTo6"));
```

Comment: sweet thats it, thanks! ill accept when it allows me.nice work.